# Can a function ([a,b] → R) with a continuous derivative have infinitely many changes in "direction"?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Can such a function be monotonically increasing and monotonically decreasing infinitely many times on some compact interval [a, b]?

If so, is there an example? If not how would I go about proving it? I'm really lost on this one to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}0 & x=0\\ x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ & x \neq 0\ \end{cases}$$

this function is continuous in [0,1] and it has infinite change in direction around *x=0*

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Note: it is continuous on $\mathbb R$, not just $[0,1]$. (Was about to say the same, but too late.)

Comment: @RichardGroenewald thanks, i will appreciate if you marked it as correct answer :)

Comment: @CiaPan thanks for the note, but he wanted it to be in [a,b]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

For example, we set 
$$f(x)=x^3\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$$
on $(0,1]$ and define $f(0)=0$. Then it is a function on $[0,1]$ with continuous 
derivative.